# Unable to access Inner class issue in java

Tags: java

local variables referenced from an inner class must be final or effectively final error is shown in the code below:

```
public Vector<Map<String, Object>> newsFeedConnection(String var, Hashtable punishment) {
    ConnectionRequest connectionRequest;
    connectionRequest = new ConnectionRequest() {
        @Override
        protected void readResponse(InputStream input) throws IOException {
            JSONParser p = new JSONParser();
            results = p.parse(new InputStreamReader(input));

            punishment = (Hashtable) results.get("punishment");
        }
    }
}
```

But when i change change it into final (code below), it gives "cannot assign a value to final variable punishment" error again.

```
public Vector<Map<String, Object>> newsFeedConnection(String var, final Hashtable punishment) {
    ConnectionRequest connectionRequest;
    connectionRequest = new ConnectionRequest() {
        @Override
        protected void readResponse(InputStream input) throws IOException {
            JSONParser p = new JSONParser();
            results = p.parse(new InputStreamReader(input));

            punishment = (Hashtable) results.get("punishment");
        }
    }
}
```

How do I solve this problem?If I set a global variable, I cannot access the value from the method in other classes.

Comment: `punishment` must be `final`, but since you can't change the refernce of `parameters`, it's actually rather pointless

Comment: that's is my exact problem if i change it into final i cannot assign a value which is what i need to do.

Comment: You might also find `punishment.putAll((Hashtable) results.get("punishment"))` will likely work better, but this assumes the `ConnectionRequest` is a blocking method call

Comment: Make a subclass of `ConnectionRequest` that includes a reference to the object that created it.  Then you can write something like `creator.setPunishment(...)`.

Comment: thankyou @MadProgrammer.. it works....
Hashtable punishmentVector = (Hashtable) results.get("punishment");
                  punishment.putAll(punishmentVector);

Comment: Sorry to bother you guys again, what to do if punishment is string instead of hashtable, i got same problem again.  punishment.concat((String) results.get("punishment"));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass by Value vs. Pass by Reference - When you pass an object reference you are doing pass by reference. When you do so you can change the state of the object by invoking appropriate methods on the object but you cannot change the reference of the object itself. For example:

```
    public class TestPassByReference {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("Lets Test!");
        changeStringDoesNotWork(stringBuilder);
        System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString());
        changeString(stringBuilder);
        System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString());
    }

    static void changeString(StringBuilder stringBuilder){
        stringBuilder.append(" Yeah I did it!");
    }

    static void changeStringDoesNotWork(StringBuilder stringBuilder){
        stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("This will not work!");
    }
}
```

The output:

```
Lets Test!               //Value did not change
Lets Test! Yeah I did it!
```

I hope now you can co-relate what you are trying to do clashes with this basic aspect and hence incorrect.

What you can do however is this:

```
HashTable tempHashTable = (Hashtable) results.get("punishment");    
punishment.clear();
punishment.putAll(tempHashTable);
```

Also why use HashTable? There are better threadsafe collection classes out there which give better performance.

Answer (score 2):

You are reinitiating a final variable which is conceptually not acceptable, just change the values inside punishment without creating it again and that will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it by updating you `punishment` variable:

```
public Vector<Map<String, Object>> newsFeedConnection(String var,  final Hashtable punishment) {
        ConnectionRequest connectionRequest;
        connectionRequest = new ConnectionRequest() {
            @Override
            protected void readResponse(InputStream input) throws IOException {
                JSONParser p = new JSONParser();
                results = p.parse(new InputStreamReader(input));

                punishment.putAll((Hashtable) results.get("punishment"));
                  }
            }
        }
}
```